How to immediately fetch updated asset list after a webhook triggers on push to main branch?
I have set up a GitHub webhook that triggers on a push to the main branch of my repository. My goal is to fetch an updated list of assets from a download_url that's included in the webhook payload. However, I am facing an issue where the data at the download_url is not immediately updated and takes a few minutes to reflect the latest changes.
Current Setup:
Webhook Configuration: The webhook is configured to trigger on push events to the main branch.
Fetching Logic: On receiving the webhook notification, my server immediately makes a GET request to the download_url provided in the webhook payload to fetch the assets.
Problem:
The assets listed at the download_url are not immediately updated after the push event. There is a delay of approximately 5 minutes before the download_url reflects the new changes.
Question:
How can I ensure that I fetch the most up-to-date asset list immediately after the webhook is triggered? Is there a way to bypass or minimize the delay in the data update at the download_url?
Attempts to Resolve:
I've tried introducing a delay before making the GET request to the download_url, but this approach is not ideal as it still doesn't guarantee that the data is the latest and also introduces unnecessary wait times.
I've considered setting up a polling mechanism to repeatedly check the download_url until the updated data appears, but this could lead to excessive requests and potential rate limiting issues.
